# how to provide spacing between groups of bars in bar chart plotly express

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, bar-chart

I have a set of data that comes in group of 3, "high", "Low", and "end". I want to treat them as a unit. However, when I display my chart, there is no spacing [image: Example Image]

In the above image, you can see that I want to have some spacing between "6A" (3 bars) and "6B" (also 3 bars). I tried the following code but it does not work for me. The `bargap` squeezes the entire chart together (no spacing) and `bargroupgap` separates each bar individually.

```
fig.update_layout(barmode='group', bargap=0.1,bargroupgap=0.0)
```